# data.table with a lubridate period class variable misbehaves after 100 rows

Tags: r, data.table

See this toy example.

Here's a sample 101 row data frame with a `lubridate::` `period` class. Yes, it is important to make it 101 because at 100 it works.

`df_arun1 <- data.frame(time2 = 1:5, timesec = rep(period(c(90, 5), c("second", "minute")), 101))`

Now we will convert this toy dataframe into a datatable,

`as.data.table(df_arun1)->dt_arun1`

And now let's try to output the datatable.

`dt_arun1`

```
Error in data.frame(time2 = 1:5, timesec = rep(period(c(90, 5), c("second",  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 101
```

But if I create a 100 row data.data.table it works.

See this:

`df_arun2 <- data.frame(time2 = 1:5, timesec = rep(period(c(90, 5), c("second", "minute")), 100))`

`as.data.table(df_arun2)->dt_arun2`

Now if you type `dt_arun2` on the command line you get all 100 rows.
But if you use `head` it fails again with the same error plus a peculiar warning.

`head(dt_arun2)`

```
 Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent
In addition: Warning message:
In cbind(time2 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1"), timesec = c("5M 90S",  :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

So what's going on here?

Comment: What is the version of `data.table` ?  It is better to show a reproducible example.  Works for this example `df_works <- data.frame(time2 = 1:5, timesec = rep(period(c(90, 5), c("second", "minute")), 5)); dt_fails <- as.data.table(df_works)` using `data.table_1.10.5`

Comment: Done @akrun. Now you have a reproducible example.